# How to create a new column that counts the number of occurrences of a value in another column and orders them by date

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a 2 column data frame with "date" and "ID" headings. Some IDs are listed more than once. I want to create a new column "Attempt" that denotes the number of attempts that each ID has taken, ordered by the date of occurrence.

Here is my sample data:

```
ID <- c(1,2,5,8,4,9,1,11,15,32,54,1,4,2,14)
Date <- c("2021-04-12", "2021-04-12", "2021-04-13", "2021-04-14", "2021-04-19", 
          "2021-04-19", "2021-04-20", "2021-04-21", "2021-04-22", "2021-04-28", 
          "2021-04-28", "2021-04-29", "2021-04-29", "2021-05-06", "2021-05-07")

Data <- data.frame(ID, Date)
Data$Date <- as.Date(Data$Date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

I tried various iterations of duplicated(). I can remove all duplicates or make every instance of a duplicated value "2" or "3" for example, but I want each occurrence to be ordered based on the date of the attempt taken.
Here is my expected result column to be added onto the original data frame:

```
Attempt <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,3,2,2,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data %>%
  group_by(ID)
  mutate(Attempt1 = row_number())

   ID       Date Attempt
1   1 2021-04-12       1
2   2 2021-04-12       1
3   5 2021-04-13       1
4   8 2021-04-14       1
5   4 2021-04-19       1
6   9 2021-04-19       1
7   1 2021-04-20       2
8  11 2021-04-21       1
9  15 2021-04-22       1
10 32 2021-04-28       1
11 54 2021-04-28       1
12  1 2021-04-29       3
13  4 2021-04-29       2
14  2 2021-05-06       2
15 14 2021-05-07       1
```

If you have the latest version of `dplyr` use

```
Data %>%
   mutate(Attempt = row_number(), .by = ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Data)[, Attempt := rowid(ID)]
```

-output

```
> Data
    ID       Date Attempt
 1:  1 2021-04-12       1
 2:  2 2021-04-12       1
 3:  5 2021-04-13       1
 4:  8 2021-04-14       1
 5:  4 2021-04-19       1
 6:  9 2021-04-19       1
 7:  1 2021-04-20       2
 8: 11 2021-04-21       1
 9: 15 2021-04-22       1
10: 32 2021-04-28       1
11: 54 2021-04-28       1
12:  1 2021-04-29       3
13:  4 2021-04-29       2
14:  2 2021-05-06       2
15: 14 2021-05-07       1
```